# ReferenceError: date is not defined

Tags: javascript, date

I have some code here where I get a value from a form represented by "adate". Then I split the string the user enters at the hyphen and separate each value into year, month and day as you can see. I use those values to define a date object. My console correctly displays the date, but I keep getting this error also showing up. Am I defining the date incorrectly? I'm not sure what the issue is.

```
function getFormData() {
    var task = document.getElementById("task").value;
    if (checkInputText(task, "Please enter a task")) return;

    var who = document.getElementById("who").value;
    if (checkInputText(who, "Please enter a person to do the task")) return;

    var adate = document.getElementById("dueDate").value;
    var reString = new RegExp("[0-9]{4}\\-\[0-9]{2}\\-\[0-9]{2}");

    if ( adate.match(reString)) {
    processDate(adate) } 

    else {
     alert("you did not enter the date in the correct format")
    };

    var id = (new Date()).getTime();
    var todoItem = new Todo(id, task, who, date);
    todos.push(todoItem);
    addTodoToPage(todoItem);
    saveTodoItem(todoItem);

    hideSearchResults();
}    


function processDate(adate) {
     var splitArray = new Array();
     splitArray = adate.split("-");
     var year = splitArray[0];
     var month = splitArray[1] - 1;
     var day = splitArray[2];
     var date = new Date(year, month, day);
     console.log(date);
    }
```

Comment: can you please add what your sample input would look like? ie "12-5-80" or what ever?

Comment: The date object also takes strings: `new Date('01/01/2013')`

Comment: The error doesn't come from your posted code. http://jsbin.com/otijin/1/edit BTW `var splitArray = new Array();` is useless, `.split()` returns a new Array object so `var splitArray = adate.split("-");` cuts out unnecessary overhead.

Comment: @elclanrs: http://xkcd.com/1179/ :-)

Comment: Could you please show us the stack trace of the exception? To me it looks like it comes not from the posted code.

Comment: May I guess? Are you trying to use `date` outside that function? Because it's declared inside the function, so it's only available there. If so, you can make `processDate` return `date`.

Comment: Ha! I was right: `var todoItem = new Todo(id, task, who, date);`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your function return the date, because the `date` variable in there is not visible to the outside:

```
function processDate(adate) {
    var splitArray = new Array();
    splitArray = adate.split("-");
    var year = splitArray[0];
    var month = splitArray[1] - 1;
    var day = splitArray[2];
    return new Date(year, month, day);
}
```

Then assign to a new variable when you call it:

```
var date = processDate(adate);
```

The error actually originated in the following line, because you were referencing a non-existing `date` variable:

```
var todoItem = new Todo(id, task, who, date);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a comment.

The RegExp constructor is usually only required where the expression is dynamically generated. Where you have a fixed expression, it's simpler to use a literal (as you don't have to quote certain characters). Also, to test the format, a more appropriate method is `test` rather than `match`.

If the date format is: yyyy-mm-dd, consider:

```
var reString = /^\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d$/; // trim leading and trailing white space?

if (reString.test(adate)) {
  processDate(adate);
}
```

The date string validation should be in the `processDate` function, which might throw different errors depending on whether the format is incorrect or the date is invalid (e.g. 2013-02-29, which will return a date of 2013-03-01 in your current code).